# Finding circumradius of regular polygon such a circle is inscribed

Tags: circles, polygons

Say we want to inscribe a cicle with a regular polygon:

[image]

The circumradius is  is the distance to the vertices of the regular n-ngon.

- We can see on the image, this circumradius of a regular n-gon is greater at lower n.
- And as n goes to infinity, the circumradius should approach the radius of the inscribed circle.

But what is the equation of the radius?

I've tried calculating it and google it, and the condition must be, the apothem of the regular n-ngon should equal the radius of the inscribed circle.

I would love your help on this.

Comment: Usually some quantity is kept constant from figure to figure. I would suggest either the side length of the polygon, or the radius of the inscribed circle, but there are many other options. You haven't mentioned anything like this in your question.

Comment: "The circumradius is the distance to the edges of the regular n-ngon" : **No**, the circumradius is the distance to the **vertices** of the regular n-ngon" It is the **inradius** which is the distance to the edges of the regular n-ngon.

Comment: why is that needed @Arthur? As I see there is only one 3-gon and 4-gon (regular pngon) that satisfies the property that it needs to inscribe a circle with radius 1.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie I updated the question.

Comment: @nammerkage If you say that the inscribed circles all have radius 1, then that's exactly the kind of thing I'm asking for. They clearly all look different in the image, and you never specified. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @Arthur makes sense, but I am looking for a general equation so just assume the inner radius of the circle is $r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I had another go at it.

let the side length of a n-polygon be $l$, let the radius of the inner circle be $r$ and let the circumradius be $R$

[image]

The side length is given by

$l = 2r  \tan(\pi / n) $

$R$, $r$ and $l/2$ forms a triangle with hypotenuse $R$. From Pythagorean we get:

$ R = \sqrt{r^2 + (\frac{l}{2})^2} $

insert value of $l$

$ R = \sqrt{r^2 + (\frac{2r  \tan(\pi / n)}{2})^2} $

$  = \sqrt{r^2 + r^2  \tan^2(\pi / n))} $

$  = r \sqrt{\tan^2(\pi / n)) +1} $

When $n \to \infty$, $R \to r$

Answer (score 1):

Perimeter of a regular polygon circumscribed around a circle *of constant given radius $r$*;

$$ p= 2 ~n ~r ~ \tan \theta = 2 ~n ~r ~ \tan \frac{2 \pi}{2n} \to  ~2 \pi r, \text{as }  n\to \infty. $$

You should draw the circle diameter contained in an equilateral triangle with same size as the other three.